# compute angle and distance between two lat and lon(point) with matlab code

Tags: matlab, google-maps

I can compute distance between two point but I cant compute angle between two point. please help me. here is my  matlab code:

```
   disp('Input the latitude and longitude of each point as prompted')
     disp('Lat and Long should be in degrees (convert minutes and seconds)')
       disp('Use negative degrees for west and south')

      lat1 = input ('Latitude point 1: ');
      lon1 = input ('Longitude point 1: ');
       lat2 = input ('Latitude point 2: ');
       lon2 = input ('Longitude point 2: ');


          latrad1 = lat1*pi/180;
            lonrad1 = lon1*pi/180;
                latrad2 = lat2*pi/180;
                     lonrad2 = lon2*pi/180;

                  londif = abs(lonrad2-lonrad1);

                 raddis = acos(sin(latrad2)*sin(latrad1)+ 
                      cos(latrad2)*cos(latrad1)*cos(londif));

                          nautdis = raddis * 3437.74677;
                         statdis = nautdis * 1.1507794;
                         stdiskm = nautdis * 1.852;
                   disp(' ')
                  fprintf('Distance in radians: = %7.4f \n', raddis);
                   fprintf('Distance in statute miles: = %7.2f \n',statdis);
                   fprintf('Distance in kilometers: = %7.2f \n', stdiskm);
```

Comment: I don't get it. Angle respect to what? Isn't the angle between *two* point always 180 degrees? You need a third point I think

Comment: @shamalaia while you're technically correct (the best kind of correct), it's a reasonable assumption that the bearing is in degrees true since these are lat-long coordinates

Comment: See: [haversine formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: Please edit and explain how this question relates to Google maps. Or remove the unrelated tag. Just having code that works with lat and lon is not enough.